# ¿Por qué la función de buscar no se ejecuta de forma correcta?

Tags: c, struct

En sí el código es de crear un sistema de registro para la alimentación de un refugio de animales y para este se pide lo que se ve en el código. La función de buscar la hago con id que está dentro de la estructura llamada Alimentación y por medio de * se asigne su valor a la variable animales.

Al momento de ejecutar esa función no sé por qué la función de buscar `(int buscar (int *id,Alimentacion*animales,int i);)` no reconoce de forma correcta lo que se pide.

Yo creo que tiene que ser algo relacionado con `posicion=buscar(id,animales,i);` ya que o no hace lo que debe hacer o termina el programa:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <time.h>
    typedef struct{
        int id;
        char mascota[20];
        char decripcionAlimento[50];
        float cantidad;
        int estado;
    }Alimentacion;
    int registrar(Alimentacion*personal,int n);
    void presentar(int i,Alimentacion*animales); 
    int buscar (int *id,Alimentacion*animales,int i);// declaracion o prototipo
    void verAnimales(Alimentacion x);
    
    int main(){
        char op=' ',resp=' ';
        int n=0,i=0,posicion=0;
        int id [11];
            Alimentacion *animales=NULL;
        char mensaje[]="\nAnimales a alimentar\n[1] Registro  \n[2] Presentar Todos \n[3] Buscar por id\n[4] Buscar por mascota y cantidad de comida\n[5]Actualizar\n[6]Elimniar\n[o]Salir\n " ;
         do{
            printf("Cuantas mascotas van a ser aliemtadas: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);fflush(stdin);
         }while(n<=0);
         animales=(Alimentacion *)malloc(n*sizeof(Alimentacion)); //arreglo dinamico
         i=0;
         do{
            printf("%s",mensaje);
            scanf("%c",&op);fflush(stdin);
            switch(op){
                case '1':if(i<n){
                         i=registrar (animales ,i);
                    }else{
                        printf("Ya no hay cupos para atencion");
                    }
                break;
                case'2': presentar(i,animales);  break;
                case'3': printf("Ingrse la id a buscar: ");
                         scanf("%d",id);fflush(stdin);
                         posicion=buscar(id,animales,i);
                         if(posicion!=1){
                              printf("\nEl animal con id  %d es: ",id);
                              verAnimales(animales[posicion]); 
                         }else
                         printf("Ciudadano con cedula %d no se encuentra ",id);
                        
                                  break;
                case'4':          break;
                case'5':          break;
                case'6':printf("Ingrese el id del animal");     
                        scanf("%d",id);fflush(stdin);
                        posicion=buscar(id,animales,i); 
                        if(posicion!=-1){
                               verAnimales(animales[posicion]);
                               printf("\nQuiere eliminar de la lista al animal a dar baja: ");
                               scanf("%c",&resp);fflush(stdin);
                              if(resp='1'){
                                   animales[posicion].estado=0;                         
                                    printf("Animal %s eliminado ",animales[posicion].mascota);
                    }
                    }                             
                     break;
             }
         }while(op!='0');
          free(animales);
         return 0;
    }
    
    int registrar (Alimentacion*personal,int i){
        
        printf("Id:  ");
        scanf("%d",&personal[i].id);fflush(stdin);
        printf("Mascota:  ");
        scanf("%s",personal[i].mascota);fflush(stdin);
        printf("Descripcion del alimento: ");
        scanf("%s",personal[i].decripcionAlimento);fflush(stdin);
        printf("Cantidad de alimento: ");
        scanf("%f",personal[i].cantidad);fflush(stdin);
        
        personal[i].estado=1;i++;
        return i;
        }
        void presentar(int n,Alimentacion*personal){
            int i=0;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(personal[i].estado==1){
                printf("Id:%d",personal[i].id);
                printf("\nDescripcion del alimento %s",personal[i].decripcionAlimento);
                printf("\nCantidad de alimento %f",personal[i].cantidad);
                                                
                  
                }   
            }
        }
    int buscar (int *id,Alimentacion*animales,int n){
        int i=0,bandera=0;// 1 es encontrado, 0 es No encontrado
        int posicion=-1;// -1 no existe
        for(i=0;i<n&&bandera==0;i++){
            if((id,animales[i].id)==0){
               posicion=i;
               bandera=1;   
            }
        }
        return posicion;
    }
    void verAnimales(Alimentacion x){
              printf("\n Id: %d",x.id);
    //        printf("\nCedula: %s",x.cedula);   
    //        printf("\nEdad: %d",x.edad);
    
           if(x.estado==0)
             printf("\nNo se lo va a alimentar.");     
    }
```

Comment: El compilador solo se encarga de verificar que la sintaxis sea correcta y traducir el código a un lenguaje que el procesador puede entender. No te dirá si la lógica está mal. Aunque puede tener la habilidad de analizar el programa e indicar algunos problemas importantes como un bucle infinito.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes comparar directamente punteros con enteros:

```
int buscar (int *id,Alimentacion*animales,int n){
    int i=0,bandera=0;// 1 es encontrado, 0 es No encontrado
    int posicion=-1;// -1 no existe
    for(i=0;i<n&&bandera==0;i++){
        if((id,animales[i].id)==0){
        //  ~~             ~~
        //  int*           int

           posicion=i;
           bandera=1;   
        }
    }
    return posicion;
}
```

En esta función no hay ninguna necesidad de que `id` sea un puntero. Los punteros están para poder pasar estructuras a las funciones o para cuando una función necesita modificar el valor de una variable y ese cambio debe poder verse fuera de dicha función... este no es el caso.

Lo más sencillo es eliminar el puntero y pasar una copia de un entero:

```
int buscar (int id, Alimentacion*animales, int n){
```

Por otro lado, date cuenta que en la comparación no estás invocando ninguna función ni nada ... el `if` no hace absolutamente nada. Para compara enteros deberías dejar el condicional así:

```
if (id == animales[i].id) {
```

Si nos vamos ahora a la función `main`, podemos ver que el uso de `id` es erróneo.

En primer lugar, `id` solo lo vas a usar para guardar un entero, luego no necesita ser un array:

```
// int id [11]; <<-- MAL
int id;
```

En segundo lugar, hay que corregir la lectura desde la terminal:

```
scanf("%d", &id);
//          ^ ya no es un puntero
```

y con estos cambios, en principio, ya debería estar

Answer (score 0):

Observaciones:

- `fflush(stdin)` no sirve de nada.
- `scanf` suele dejar saltos de línea, provocando comportamientos inesperados. Necesitas leerlos con una función como [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar).

  Puedes crear una función como esta para dicho propósito de manera que te asegures de solo limpiar saltos de línea:

  ```
  void limpiar(){
      int c = 0;
      do {
          c = getchar();
      } while (c == '\n');
      fseek(stdin, -1, SEEK_CUR);
  }
  ```
- `scanf` lee cadenas de texto hasta el primer espacio o salto de línea que encuentre. Mejor usa [`gets_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) que lee hasta el primer salto de línea o el número de caracteres indicado.
- ¿Seguro que en la función `buscar` quieres un puntero como id? Me parece que en realidad quieres pasar un entero común y corriente.
- La condición del if en la función `buscar` es rara. En lugar de `(id,animales[i].id)==0`, probablemente quieras usar `id == animales[i].id`.

Corrigiendo la función `buscar` quedaría así:

```
int buscar (int id, Alimentacion*animales, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(id == animales[i].id){
           return i;  
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```